# Remove <noscript> tag inside DIV

Tags: jquery

I want to print plain text contained in variable `my_data` within `div` element with `.order_summary_payment` class. My first line is an attempt to remove `<noscript>` tag element, because otherwise its contents are printed with `text()` method, but `<noscript>` tag's contents are still in output.

```js
my_data = $('label').not('noscript').text();
$('div.order_summary_payment').text(my_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
    mytext
    <img src="https://image-link.com/logo.png" alt="alttext">
    <noscript>
        <img src="https://image-link.com/logo.png" alt="alttext">     
    </noscript>
</label>
```

Comment: Possible to include a sample of the HTML?

Comment: I edited my question and included structure inside matched label element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.not()` just filters out elements from the collection itself, it doesn't remove child elements. Since your collection is just `<label>` elements, there are no `<noscript>` elements at the top-level of the collection, they're nested inside.

What you need to do is clone the elements (so you don't modify the real DOM), then remove the `<noscript>` elements from the cloned DOM hierarchy:

```
my_elements = $('.wc_payment_methods input:checked').siblings('label').clone();
my_elements.find("noscript").remove();
my_data = my_elements.text();
```